# Tap to click enabling with console Command

Tags: touchpad, command-line

What is a command for enabling tap-to-click through console please? My trackpad's left/right buttons don't work on my laptop and I currently don't have a mouse at home I could use so I need it to be enabled. Without ttap-to-click I can't use my elementary os.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable tap-to-click with follow command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope your keyboard works for that's what the following method uses.

Here are the steps you need to do:

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
2. Search and Open Settings by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>
3. In settings, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and Enter "Mouse"
4. Using Keyboard Arrows select and open "Mouse and Track pad Settings"
5. Once there, use the Tab key to select the "Tap to Click" Setting
6. Use <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle the setting on.